# Encoding and Decoding In Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

My script encodes text and outputs random strings. It is different each time and loads a dictionary that has been pre-set by my dictionary gen.py (included after the main script). I've started my basic Tkinter GUI and this is not the finishing GUI. The main code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, pickle
from Tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
root = Tk()

def error(msg):
    result.delete("1.0", END)
    result.insert(END, msg)

def encode(string):
    y = random.randrange(0, 200)
    idNo = y + 40
    idNo = idNo * 7
    idNo = idNo - 32
    idNo = idNo * 6
    idNo = idNo + 3
    idNo = str(idNo)
    idLength = 4
    idLetters = list(idNo)
    base = 'dict/base.txt'
    with open(str(base), "rb") as fp:
        dictionary = pickle.load(fp)
    for i in xrange(0, int(idLength)):
        letter = idLetters[0]
        value = dictionary[str(letter)]
        idLetters.remove(letter)
        idLetters.append(value)
    idNo = ''.join(idLetters)

    firstidNo = idNo[:2]
    lastidNo = idNo[-2:]

    letters = list(string)
    length = len(string)
    chosendict = "dict/" + str(y) + ".txt"
    with open(str(chosendict), "rb") as fp:
        dictionary = pickle.load(fp)
    for i in xrange(0, int(length)):
        letter = letters[0]
        value = dictionary[str(letter)]
        letters.remove(letter)
        letters.append(value)

    encoded = ''.join(letters)
    text = str(firstidNo) + encoded + str(lastidNo)
    original = decode(text)
    if original != string:
        return ("Error: Encoding Unsuccessful\nPlease Contact Whoever gave this program")
    else:
        return text

def decode(inputdecode):
    firstidNo = inputdecode[:2]
    lastidNo = inputdecode[-2:]
    idNo = str(firstidNo) + str(lastidNo)
    base = 'dict/rbase.txt'
    with open(str(base), "rb") as fp:
        dictionary = pickle.load(fp)
    idLength = 4
    idLetters = list(idNo)
    for i in xrange(0, int(idLength)):
        letter = idLetters[0]
        value = dictionary[str(letter)]
        idLetters.remove(letter)
        idLetters.append(value)
    idNo = ''.join(idLetters)
    idNo = int(idNo)
    idNo = idNo - 3
    idNo = idNo / 6
    idNo = idNo + 32
    idNo = idNo / 7
    idNo = idNo - 40
    chosendict = "dict/r" + str(idNo) + '.txt'
    with open(str(chosendict), "rb") as fp:
        dictionary = pickle.load(fp)
    string = inputdecode[:-2]
    string = string[2:]
    letters = list(string)


    length = len(string)
    for i in xrange(0, int(length)):
        letter = letters[0]
        value = dictionary[str(letter)]
        letters.remove(letter)
        letters.append(value)

    decoded = ''.join(letters)
    text = decoded
    return text

def guiencode():
    string = encoding.get("1.0","end-1c")
    text = encode(string)
    result.delete("1.0", END)
    result.insert(END, text)

def guidecode():
    inputdecode = decoding.get("1.0","end-1c")
    text = decode(inputdecode)
    result.delete("1.0", END)
    result.insert(END, text)

root.title('Encoder V2.0')

timesNewRoman = Font(family="Arial", size=10)
height1 = 2
width1 = 40

encoding = Text(root, height=height1, width=width1)
encoding.pack()
encoding.configure(font=timesNewRoman)
buttonToEncode = Button(root, text = "Encode", command=lambda: guiencode()).pack(pady=2)
decoding = Text(root, height=height1, width=width1)
decoding.pack(pady=3)
decoding.configure(font=timesNewRoman)
buttonToDecode = Button(root, text = "Decode", command=lambda: guidecode()).pack(pady=2)
result = Text(root, height=height1, width=width1)
result.pack()
result.configure(font=timesNewRoman)


root.mainloop()
```

As you can see it chooses a dictionary and then through a non-changing dictionary it encodes the id for that dictionary. As there are 200 dictionaries the number it generates (`idNo`) is always 4 digits so it splits it into 2 and puts two at the front and two at the back.

I also use a gen.py file which generates my dictionary files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, pickle
all_chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
             'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
             '!','"','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','-','+','=','{','}','[',']',':',';','@',"'",'~','#','<','>',',','.','/','?','|',
             '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ']
all_chars2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
             'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
             '!','"','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','-','+','=','{','}','[',']',':',';','@',"'",'~','#','<','>',',','.','/','?','|',
             '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ']
dictionary1 = {}
dictionary2 = {}

length = len(all_chars)
print(length)

for x in range(0, 201):
    random.shuffle(all_chars2)
    for i in xrange(0, 93):
        dictionary1[all_chars[i]] = str(all_chars2[i])
        dictionary2[all_chars2[i]] = str(all_chars[i])
    #print(dictionary1)
    #print(dictionary2)
    #print('dictionary' + str(x) + str(dictionary1))
    dicname = 'dict/' + str(x) +'.txt'
    with open(str(dicname), "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(dictionary1, fp)
    dicname = 'dict/r' + str(x) + '.txt'
    with open(str(dicname), "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(dictionary2, fp)

random.shuffle(all_chars2)
for i in xrange(0, 93):
    dictionary1[all_chars[i]] = str(all_chars2[i])
    dictionary2[all_chars2[i]] = str(all_chars[i])
#print(dictionary1)
#print(dictionary2)
#print('dictionary' + str(x) + str(dictionary1))
dicname = 'dict/base.txt'
with open(str(dicname), "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(dictionary1, fp)
dicname = 'dict/rbase.txt'
with open(str(dicname), "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(dictionary2, fp)
```

Anything I can do to improve my code is appreciated as well as features that would be nice for me to add (Things like encoding/decoding history etc.)

Thanks!

NB/ I know I overuse `int()` and `str()`, its just a habit I'm in to stop me getting errors!

EDIT:

A picture of the current GUI

[image: MY GUI]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to review all of your code (at least for now), but here's some recommendations:

- If I'm not mistaken, `xrange` starts at `0` if no first argument is given (this is the case with `range` in Python 3). So unless you need to start at another initial value, leave out the first argument and just call `xrange(<upper bound>)`. The same goes for `random.randrange`, by the way.
- Some of your variable names are not descriptive. In particular `dictionary1` and `dictionary2`, and `all_chars2`. As I didn't go through all of your code, I have no clue why you're using two seperate dictionaries, but you'd probably be able to get rid of the second one by rewriting your program slightly.
- Make use of the `string` module:

  ```
  >>> import string
  >>> string.ascii_lowercase
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  >>> string.ascii_uppercase
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  >>> string.digits
  '0123456789'
  >>> string.punctuation
  '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
  ```
- There's no need to cast the filename to a string:

  ```
  dicname = 'dict/base.txt'
  # Anyone remotely familiar with Python understands that dicname is a `str`
  with open(str(dicname), "wb") as fp:
  # Confusing, because this makes it seem as though it's not a `str`
  ```

Comment: thanks, if only I knew about the string module before, could have saved myself ages...

Answer (score 2):

The improvements I would like to suggest are related to Tkinter only:

Starting with the imports, do not use wildcard imports. I mean, instead of coding `from Tkinter import *`, write `import Tkinter as Tk`. Then you will need to prefix all the widgets you use with `Tk`. The main interest of this approach is that in case you want to use the [themed widgets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html), you will not have namespaces clashes as described [here](https://www.begueradj.com/tkinter-best-practices.html).

In history, graphical user interfaces spurred the object-oriented design. So it is nice you to use a class to build your GUI because, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application), *this gives you a private namespace for all of your callbacks and private functions, and just generally makes it easier to organize your code. In a procedural style you have to code top-down, defining functions before using them, etc. With this method you don't since you don't actually create the main window until the very last step. I prefer inheriting from tk.Frame just because I typically start by creating a frame, but it is by no means necessary.*

I suggest you to create a class

```
import Tkinter as Tk 


class MyGUI(Tk.Frame): # Please use a better class name

    def __init__(self, master):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.configure_gui()
        self.create_widgets()
```

This is a good design. All what you have to do now is to complete coding the `configure_gui()` and `create_widgets()` functions above. For instance, all the settings of your interface should be put in the configuration function like follows:

```
def configure_gui(self):
   self.master.title('Encoder V2.0')
   # continue if any ...
```

Then create the widgets as follows:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.encoding = Tk.Text(self.master, height=..., width=...)
    # Note how I replace "root" by "self.master"
    # Use better names, "encoding" is not a good name to instantiate a Text widget.
```